# Can't load image form local storage into struts 2 view page in browser?

Tags: html, struts2

When I try to display an image from local storage in browser through a struts 2 action page, the image cannot be loaded and is not displayed despite the img src file showing the location in local disk partition correctly. Please any one help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Here is the struts 2 code:
`<img src= "<s:property value="profilePicture"/>" height="150" width="150" align="middle" />`

This is the output I get in browser:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Place your image on the servlet (outside WEB-INF) and fetch it from there.

I assume you have a folder structure for your web application. In general it will look sth like descibed in here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/gexap.html

So keep your images in the root directory of your project. Otherwise can you imagine the security implications if someone could start accessing data that exist on your local drive?

Also check this older post that is related to what you are asking:

[How to get server local drive path in web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038314/how-to-get-server-local-drive-path-in-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

If your file is in your local hard disk, which seems strange, the only problem is your image addressing.

If your image is at `d:\profile_pictures\uploaded_aaa_bbb.jpeg` the `<s:property value="profilePicture"/>` should return exactly this. You can easily test it by copy `d:\profile_pictures\uploaded_aaa_bbb.jpeg` to address bar to and see if you can see the image.